# How to change every max value to 1, others 0 along column, in matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of shape `(10,10000)`. For each column in matrix, I want to have a `1` at max value index and other values `0`. Is there any way to avoid `for` loops?

Comment: One way is `(matrix == matrix.max(0)).astype(matrix.dtype)`, although if the max value is repeated in some column you would get `1` on all of its positions.

Comment: If you don't want that you can do `(matrix.argmax(0) == np.arange(len(matrix))[:, np.newaxis]).astype(matrix.dtype)`.

Comment: Or `np.identity(len(mat))[:, mat.argmax(0)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using numpy. First import numpy and convert your matrix to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
my_mat = np.asarray(my_original_mat)
```

Now an example with a small matrix:

```
mat = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(4, 4))
# array([[3, 9, 3, 1],
#       [1, 4, 2, 3],
#       [8, 4, 4, 2],
#       [7, 7, 3, 7]])
new_mat = np.zeros(mat.shape)  # our zeros and ones will go here
new_mat[np.argmax(mat, axis=0), np.arange(mat.shape[1])] = 1
# array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Basically using numpy slicing to get around needing for loops. The `new_mat[np.argmax(...), np.arange(...)]` line specifies, for each column, which row contains the max value, and sets these row-column pairs to 1. Seems to work.

Note that if you have repeated max values, this only sets the first (top-most) max value to 1.

Another option that gives you 1s for *every* max value, including repeated ones (I see jdehesa beat me to it in the comments, but repeated here for completeness):

```
(mat == mat.max(axis=0)).astype(mat.dtype)
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. I tested it with the same code above and using a random seed = 123

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite easy to create this matrix in sparse storage.

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
>>> 
>>> m, n = 3, 7
>>> 
>>> data = np.random.randint(0, 10, (m, n))
>>> 
>>> data
array([[9, 0, 0, 7, 3, 1, 3],
       [8, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 5, 7, 5, 3]])
>>> 
>>> result = csc_matrix((np.ones(n), data.argmax(0), np.arange(n+1)), (m, n))
>>> result
<3x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> result.A
array([[1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```